# Updating blank values with nulls in all the columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a table with 50 columns. This table contains nulls in all the columns but in random. I want to update all the nulls with 'no data'. If there are nulls in 2 columns I can do it with

```
update tableName 
set col1 = 'nodata' 
where col1 is null
```

But, I have 50 columns like this, instead of writing an `update` command for all the columns, is there any other technique to complete it in a single line query.

Comment: I'd keep the nulls. They do have a purpose.

Comment: *I want to update all the nulls with 'no data'.* Do not alter original source data, substitute in retrieving queries.

Comment: Consider you do `max(col1)` and get `nodata` as result... Very confusing.

Comment: Sounds impossible in generic case, because you cannot update `date '2021-04-21'` with `'nodata'`. This is a display task and should be addressed to the application side.

Comment: Also please leave only a single tag of your DBMS: Oracle is about [Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/), MySQL is about [MySQL database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/). It is described at the header of the page after you click on tag. Do not mix them together, they are different

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
update tableName
    set col1 = coalesce(col1, 'nodata'),
        col2 = coalesce(col2, 'nodata'),
        . . .;
```

If most rows have data in all columns, you can add a `where` clause:

```
where col1 is not null or col2 is not null or . . .
```

Note:  This answers your question, but I don't think it is a good idea.  `NULL` is a perfectly good way to represent "no data" in a SQL database.  There is no need to update the values.  In addition, this assumes that all columns are strings.  This method will not work on other data types -- you will likely get a type conversion error.